# CSS Flexbox: Align last nth items towards the end

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a few "div" 's inside a "nav":

```
<nav>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
</nav>
```

I want to align div A,B,C,D at the top, but div E and F at the bottom:

This code works for the last item (F), but E floats exactly in the middle:

```
nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
  
        & > div:nth-child(5),
        & > div:nth-child(6) {
          margin-top: auto;
        }
}
```

[image]

How can I make div E stick with div F at the bottom (without extra wrapping div's inside the nav)?

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gajtqfn9/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this two ways below.

Using `nth-child()`

Use `margin-top:auto` on `nth-child(5)` only to get your desired results

**Live demo:**

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
}

div:nth-child(5) {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
</nav>
```

Using `:nth-last-child()`

You can also use [nth-last-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) to achieve this.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
}

div:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
</nav>
```